# How to make hr display at the same line

Tags: html, css

So a want to display `<hr>` in my three divs at the same line like this
http://5.firepic.org/5/images/2015-11/20/wh5b8qaogym8.png

I tried to display: flex the parent div but it doesn't help.
Thank you for any help!
https://jsfiddle.net/ex2108q7/

```
<section class="blog">
<div class="container">
<h2>blog</h2>
<div class="row">
<div class="blog-wrapper">
<article class="four columns">
<img src="http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/675x380/2014/09/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="">
<span>elegant, creative, and memorable</span>
<p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents.I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the</p>
<hr>
<span class="date">AUG 22, 2013</span><a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
</article>
<article class="four columns">
<img src="http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/675x380/2014/09/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="">
<span>elegant, creative, and memorable</span>
<p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents.I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the</p>
<hr>
<span class="date">AUG 22, 2013</span><a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
</article>
<article class="four columns">
<img src="http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/675x380/2014/09/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="">
<span>elegant, creative, and memorable</span>
<p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents.I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the</p>
<hr>
<span class="date">AUG 22, 2013</span><a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
</article>
</div>
</div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What's the issue with the demo you posted?

Comment: If you post the the html above in your jsfiddle example it works :)

Comment: can't you give your article a min-height?

Comment: you can also try 'boder-bottom' in styles for that column

Comment: Yeah...a bottom border would be the optimal method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set the `hr`, `date span`, and `read_more` link to `position:absolute;` They're positioned to the bottom of the div. The `.four` div has a padding bottom of 40px which gives us this extra space.

The `hr`'s will always be aligned across different screen widths and if the content of each `div` is different heights.

https://jsfiddle.net/ex2108q7/5/

```
.blog {
    padding-top: 100px;
    background: #3a3146
}
.blog-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
}
.blog-wrapper .four {position:relative; margin:5px; padding-bottom:40px; -webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;}

.blog-wrapper .four hr {
    width:100%; position:absolute; bottom:20px;
}

.blog p {
    color: #a397ad;
    font-size: 0.667em; 
}
.blog span {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.208em;
}
.blog img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.blog .read_more {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    right:10px;
    float: right;
    color: #c6c4ba;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.583em;
}
.read_more:hover {
    color: #afada1;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.blog .date {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    color: #8b8194;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.583em;
    clear:left;
}
```

---

## Update

Now works on Firefox:

https://jsfiddle.net/ex2108q7/7/

```
.blog-wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I was looking your fiddle in firefox and columns are not inline but they are in chrome.

Comment: Good answer, you got +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ex2108q7/2/

The following change is made:

```
.blog {
    padding-top: 100px;
    background: #3a3146
}
```

is changed to

```
.blog p {
    color: #a397ad;
    font-size: 0.667em; 
    min-height:100px;
    max-height:100px;
}
```

I noticed you have a read more button, So If you limit your `<p></p>` to always have a x amount of characters you should be fine.

Comment: This doesn't work when you resize the content frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you can get `hr` to always be inline is if you set fixed `height` on p and title and `overflow-hidden` like this https://jsfiddle.net/ex2108q7/3/

**CSS**

```
.blog {
    background: #3a3146
}
.blog-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.blog-wrapper .four {-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;}

.blog p {
    color: #a397ad;
    font-size: 0.667em; 
}
.blog span {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.208em;
}
.blog img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.blog .read_more {
    float: right;
    color: #c6c4ba;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.583em;
}
.read_more:hover {
    color: #afada1;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.blog .date {
    color: #8b8194;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 0.583em;
}

.article-title {
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
}

.columns p {
    height: 70px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted this to by dynamic so a height wouldn't have to be set, and it would work across different screen widths.

Comment: @Darren Gourley if there is a way to do that what you said with different content and title size i would like to hear it :)

Comment: There is, see my submitted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Flexbox, you have to tell the articles to be columns.

Then you tell the `hr` to push itself as far down as possible.

```
article.columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

hr {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ex2108q7/6/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place your "articles" in three columns, here is the easiest way to do it:

```
   <style>
   .blog-wrapper
   {/* # of columns. Pay attention to the comments: */
    -moz-column-count: 3; 
    -webkit-column-count: 3; 
    column-count: 3; 
   }
   .blog-wrapper
   {
    -moz-column-gap:6px;
    -webkit-column-gap:6px; 
    column-gap:6px; 
    -moz-column-rule:  thin dotted gray ;
    -webkit-column-rule:  thin dotted gray ;
    column-rule:  thin dotted gray ;
     padding: 0px ; 
     width: auto ; 
   }
   </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed four columns to four-columns and added code.

```
.four-columns img {width: 30%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
.four-columns {width: 30%; float: left;}
```

Changed your blog wrapper by adding code.

```
.blog-wrapper { width: 100%;}
```

I removed blog.img by commenting it out.

```
/*.blog img { width: 100%; height: auto;}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several issues there. It seems that you've used  as an ID but it actually can't play this role so I'd suggest to remove all

---

s at first. Then it seems you used Bootstrap to design your page. However you have only one .container and only one .row and no .col-md's. These are what will allow you to design you're three columns... Here is what I've done :

```
    <section class="blog">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row" style="text-align:center; margin-top:5%; margin-bottom:5%; color:white">

                <h2>blog</h2>

            </div>


            <div class="row">

                <div class="blog-wrapper col-md-offset-2 col-md-8" style="text-align:justify; background-color:#33001a; padding:2%; color:#b3b3b3">

                    <article class="col-md-4">

                        <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/675x380/2014/09/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="">

                        </div>

                        <span>elegant, creative, and memorable</span>
                        <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents.I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the</p>

                        <span class="date">AUG 22, 2013</span><a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>

                    </article>

                    <article class="col-md-4">

                        <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/675x380/2014/09/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="">

                        </div>

                        <span>elegant, creative, and memorable</span>
                        <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents.I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the</p>

                        <span class="date">AUG 22, 2013</span><a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>

                    </article>

                    <article class="col-md-4">

                         <div class="thumbnail">

                            <img src="http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/675x380/2014/09/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg" alt="">

                        </div>

                        <span>elegant, creative, and memorable</span>
                        <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents.I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the</p>

                        <span class="date">AUG 22, 2013</span><a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>

                    </article>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

I gave your title span a class of "title" and applied the CSS you had for ".blog span" to that.
I also wrapped your column footer in a div that has a styles applied to it `display: block;` so both the date and "read more" link are contained in an element and can be on the same line.

**CSS**

As @Pauli_D stated, if you're using flex, you need to make the articles know they are columns

```
.blog-wrapper .columns {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
}
```

The display for the ".blog-wrapper .four" should just be "flex", "-webkit-flex", and "-ms-flex", but not "-webkit-box-flex" (that's not a thing as far as I know).

```
.blog-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;  /* not sure if needed- IE is silly */
    display: flex;
}



.blog-wrapper .four {
    -webkit-flex: 1;     
    -ms-flex: 1;         /* needed for IE 10 (9 and below don't support flex at all) */
    flex: 1;
    margin: .75em .25em; /* optional formatting - remove margin to have content fill entire column */
}
```

The hr needs a `margin-top: auto;` to force it down as far as it can go. It also needs a `width: 100%;` (or whatever % you prefer) to expand to the the column width.

```
hr {
    margin-top: auto;       /* needed to force hr down */
    width: 100%;            /* needed to extend hr to full width. you can choose the % – I kept it 100% to fill column width sans padding */
    height: 1px;            /* everything on this line and below for hr are optional - read here for help: http://3internet.com/resources/Design/theHRtag.aspx */
    border: 0;              
    color: #fff;            /* certain browsers require this */ 
    background-color: #fff; /* certain browsers require this: Chrome, Firefox, Safari  */

}
```

**My JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/z7jse8z3/

**Snippet**

```css
.blog {
  padding-top: 100px;
  background: #3a3146
}
.blog-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.blog-wrapper .columns {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.blog-wrapper .four {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  margin: .75em .25em;
  /* optional formatting - remove margin to have content fill entire column */
}
.blog p {
  color: #a397ad;
  font-size: 0.667em;
}
.blog .title {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.208em;
}
.blog img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
hr {
  margin-top: auto;
  /* needed to force hr down */
  width: 100%;
  /* needed to extend hr to full width. you can choose the % – I kept it 100% to fill column width sans padding */
  height: 1px;            /* everything on this line and below for hr are optional - read here for help: http://3internet.com/resources/Design/theHRtag.aspx *
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  /* certain browsers require this */
  background-color: #fff;
  /* certain browsers require this: Chrome, Firefox, Safari  */
}
.blog .read_more {
  color: #c6c4ba;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 0.583em;
  float: right;
}
.read_more:hover {
  color: #afada1;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.blog .date {
  float: left;
  color: #8b8194;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 0.583em;
}
```

```html
<section class="blog">
    <div class="container">
         <h2>blog</h2>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="blog-wrapper">
                <article class="four columns">
                    <img src="http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/675x380/2014/09/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg" alt=""> <span class="title">elegant, creative, and memorable</span>
                    <p>A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart. I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents. I should be incapable of drawing a single stroke at the</p>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="article_footer"> <span class="date">AUG 22, 2013</span><a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="four columns">
                    <img src="http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/675x380/2014/09/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg" alt=""> <span class="title">Pavneet & Raj - dreams do come true</span>

                    <p>When, y valley teems with vapour around me, and the meridian sun strikes the upper surface of the impenetrable foliage of my trees, and but a few stray gleams steal into the inner sanctuary, I throw myself down. I lie close to the earth, a thousand unknown plants are noticed by me: when I hear the buzz of the little world among the stalks, and grow familiar with the countless indescribable forms of the insects.</p>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="article_footer"> <span class="date">AUG 22, 2013</span><a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="four columns">
                    <img src="http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/675x380/2014/09/too_good_for_grumpy_cat.jpg" alt=""> <span class="title">Matthew and jenny - a journey to a new life</span>

                    <p>A collection of textile samples lay spread out on the table - Samsa was a travelling salesman - and above it there hung a picture that he had recently cut out of an illustrated magazine and house It showed a lady fitted out with a fur hat and fur boa who sat upright, raising a heavy fur muff that covered the whole of her lower arm towards the viewer. among the stalks, and grow familiar with the countless indescribable forms of the insects.</p>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="article_footer"> <span class="date">AUG 22, 2013</span><a href="" class="read_more">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make `<img>`, `<span>` and `<p>` to have static height. So that `<hr>` will be on straight